# How to set up Node server on Neutralino?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, neutralinojs

I didn't find any informations about how to config a backend for a neutralino app, so I can access to system resources, like Electron does with background.js . Should I connect (if possible) to the internal websocket server, as specified [here](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/configuration/neutralino.config.json#enableserver-boolean)

```
devAPIServer listening at http://localhost:5050
```

or create one from scratch, by using Socket or Express.
In any case, I'd like to write it in a different js file than main.js . But how to boot it concurrently with the app, especially in production mode. All I've got in mind is this:

```
Neutralino.os.execCommand('node server.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used much Electron, but i can try to answer if i understood correctly what you are asking.

Neutralino works more like a native view for web files, so a web app can be run as a native app on Desktops.
It does not provide direct access to the backend that make the web resources available.
but it gives some API to interact with the system, this for example for reading and writing files https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/filesystem.
Everything must be done only on the web files of the frontend.

In the Roadmap there is mention about Extensions that sould allow to extend the backend capabilities, but haven't look much into them i can't say for sure
https://github.com/neutralinojs/roadmap#specs-api-extensions

Comment: The extensions thing is interesting, but it's just been created, so I don't know exactly when it will be released. Meanwhile, I'm using os.execCommand, but I don't want to pack server files, if not included inside res.neu file .